# How to hide the Microphone Camera on/off overlay on upper right corner of monitor in Windows

Tags: windows, microphone, camera, overlay

A microphone/camera on/off overlay appeared on the upper right corner of my monitor. How can I hide it?

[image]

Thank you

Comment: If you have a third party Camera/Microphone, check the software settings for such.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It seems that you have PowerToys installed on your PC.

1. Open PowerToys
2. Go to Video conferencing, Toolbar position. Change it from there.

If there is no option to hide it, you can set "Enable Video Conference" to Off.

Comment: Thanks! I just turned off Video Conference completely. I just use FancyZones from PowerToys. I might have pressed its shortcut key accidentally.

Answer (score 1):

If it's disabled but displayed, just go to the bottom right (taskbar) and right click on powertoys, and then click close. Re-open it and it should let you disable it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).